# Is it allowed to specialize a template with enums with the same integral value?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Look at this simple snippet:

```
enum class Enum1 { Value };
enum class Enum2 { Value };
template <auto> struct Foo;
template <> struct Foo<Enum1::Value> { };
template <> struct Foo<Enum2::Value> { };
```

Clang compiles this, but gcc-7.2 fails:

> x.cpp:5:20: error: redefinition of ‘struct Foo<(Enum1)0>’  template <>
>   struct Foo { };

This error message seems invalid, as at line 5, `Enum2::Value` is written.

Which compiler is correct? Is this conforming code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct#:deduction,placeholder_type):

> A type `T` containing a placeholder type, and a corresponding initializer `e`, are determined as follows:
>
> - for a non-type template parameter declared with a type that contains a placeholder type, `T` is the declared type of the non-type template parameter and `e` is the corresponding template argument.

This seems to suggest that the deduced type would be `decltype(Enum1::Value)`, and the value would be `Enum1::Value`.

---

Is `decltype(Enum1::Value)` equal to `decltype(Enum2::Value)`? This code...

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(Enum1::Value), decltype(Enum2::Value)>);
```

...fails to compile with both **clang++ 6** and **g++ 8**.

---

I *think* that you *might* have exposed a bug in gcc. As [Johannes Schaub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) pointed out in the comments, there's also a [paragraph in favour of gcc's behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type).

There's a bug report open: [**#79092**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79092).

---

Also note that the following code is accepted by both compilers:

```
template <typename T, T> struct Foo;
template <> struct Foo<decltype(Enum1::Value), Enum1::Value> { };
template <> struct Foo<decltype(Enum2::Value), Enum2::Value> { };
```

`template <auto>` behaving differently from that would be (IMHO) suprising and undesired.

Comment: This paragraph appears to indicate that GCC is correct to not include the type for the non-type template argument when comparing the template-ids of the explicit specializations: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type (BTW the difference can be easier exposed simply by trying `Foo<0>` vs `Foo<0L>`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - Are you referring to *"their corresponding non-type template arguments of integral or enumeration type have identical values and"*? It most certainly applies in the case `template<Enum> struct Foo`, since both values are of the same type. But I don't think it's quite clear cut and try in this case. Is there any sort of decay that should occur like in the `0` vs `0L` case?

Comment: Besides, the GCC error indicates **it is** aware of the type.

Comment: For what its worth, [clang and gcc seems to disagree on whether they are the same](https://godbolt.org/g/YVTN4x), in a simpler case

Comment: But given that the parameters have different type, I don't think that the `Foo<0>` is supposed to be the same type as `Foo<0L>`. That's beyond my comfort zone anyway, so I'll wait for someone else to explain.

Comment: Well, the standard also says [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#arg.nontype-2). *"a converted constant expression of the type of the template-parameter"*. That indicates the type *should* be taken into account. I think neither Clang nor GCC can be held at fault here. This may warrant a defect report. It should be crystal clear.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb apparently, gcc performs some non trivial conversion when determining the specialization non type argument type used for type equivalence; compare the [non-demangled output](https://godbolt.org/g/ks1Nks), gcc seems even behaving in a value dependent way! this suggests a gcc bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! "there's also a paragraph in favour of gcc's behavior." I don't think that it is in favor of gcc. I think that temp.type 1) simply doesn't cover this case, or 2) if it does cover, but this case in favor of clang (as `Enum1::Value` cannot be compared to`Enum2::Value`, so we cannot say that they have identical values, even though their integral values are the same).

Comment: As for `0` vs `0L`, as they can be compared, and can be considered equal, I agree with StoryTeller, the standard should be more clear on this. It should describe exactly how `auto` template-arguments are handled for type-equivalence.

Comment: I suspect wording defect, given that [\[temp.param\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#4) diverged from [\[temp.type\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type#1) when it comes to non-type arguments.